# Wait for parent component/module to load data

Tags: angular, typescript

> **Please note:** I know there is `APP_INITIALIZER` but this seems to work only on the top-level module (**app.module.ts**) of the application.

I have as parent component which loads some data:

In **admin-area.component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

  forkJoin([
    this._userService.getMe(),
    this._placeService.getAll()
    ])
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.afterInit()))
    .subscribe(
      ([user, businesses]) => {
        this._appState.user = user;
        this._appState.businesses = businesses;
        this.afterInit();
      }
    );
}
```

The problem is that there are child components which rely on `this._appState.user` and `this._appState.businesses`.

I cannot load this with `APP_INITIALIZER` because the above data is only loaded, if the user is logged in. The "logged-in" area is a lazy-loaded module on it own.

So, the question is rather simple:

How can I make sure my data is loaded before child components try to display themselves?

This:

```
providers: [
  AdminAreaState,
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: adminAreaInit, deps: [AdminAreaState], multi: true}
]
```

Does not work. `adminAreaInit()` is not getting called. This only works for my top-level module **app.module.ts**. So, `APP_INITIALIZER` does not seem to work on any other module, is that corrent?

What are my options here?

---

I think I need to provide some more details.

Note, that I am already trying to use `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="!business?.servicePlan">
  Please Upgrade
</div>
```

but the problem is that if I navigate to this particular page and *refresh* the page, `business` is always `undefined`. `business` is a result of finding the right `business` in the Array of `businesses` using the `businessId`.

At the time the child component gets loaded, I load additional data. In this case some reviews (comments).

Now, `loadPage()` loads *one* page of my requrested data for a business. `_appState` is a service which is supposed to be loaded first. If I do this:

```
  private loadPage() {
    console.log(this._appState);
    console.log(this._appState.businesses);
    this._appState.businesses.forEach(
      (b) => {
        console.log(b);
      });
    setTimeout(() => this._appState.businesses.forEach(
      (b) => {
        console.log(b);
      }
    ), 100);

    const businessId = this._appState.businessId;
    this.business = this._appState.businesses.find(b => b.id === businessId);
  }
```

This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see `this._appState` *has* businesses but `this._appState.businesses` does print an empty array.

`_appState.businesses` is just an `Observable`:

`ApplicationState` service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationState {

  public businessIdChange;

  public businessesChange;

  private _user = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel>(null);

  private _businessId = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);

  private _businesses = new BehaviorSubject<Array<BusinessModel>>([]);

  constructor() {
    this.businessIdChange = this._businessId.asObservable();
    this.businessesChange = this._businesses.asObservable();
  }

  set user(value: UserModel) {
    this._user.next(value);
  }

  get user(): UserModel {
    return this._user.getValue();
  }

  set businessId(businessId: number) {

    if (businessId === this.businessId) {
      return;
    }

    this._businessId.next(businessId);
  }

  get businessId() {
    return this._businessId.getValue();
  }

  set businesses(value) {
    this._businesses.next(value);
  }

  get businesses(): Array<BusinessModel> {
    return this._businesses.getValue();
  }

}
```

I have no idea why I see this and I thought pre-loading the data would make sense anyway. But maybe I have a different issue here?

Comment: Is there something to prevent to use `*ngIf="_appstate_user"` in the template where the child components are loaded ?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191231/module-equivalent-of-app-initializer-in-angular

Comment: @SGalea Can this work with `forkJoin` ?

Comment: I would use the technique @edkeveked suggested or resolvers.

Comment: @SGalea Actually, this is what I am already doing but it is a problem when I refresh the page on that particular route. I added more details to my question.

Comment: This application might need some refactoring however you can solve this issue quickly <div *ngIf="business">
<div *ngIf="!business?.servicePlan">
  Please Upgrade
</div>
</div>  Read about Smart/Dumb components and OnPush change detection it will make your code very elegant and easier to reason about.

Comment: @SGalea Not a beautiful solution but a workaround. I agree. This requires some refactorization. The thing here is that one can manage multiple businesses and I messed up the shared state of the parent component a little bit right there.

Answer (score 2):

Use Angular Resolvers on component level. Check [this](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/) for more information.

Comment: I just tried this. It only works in the sense of "the data gets loaded" but the child is still rendered before the data has completely arrived.

Comment: @displayname can you show me your resolver? Usually Resolvers return with resolve() an Observable which is resolved before the component is rendered so the data is available

Comment: Since my question is already quite huge I pasted it here: https://pastecode.xyz/view/227132a3 I am just returning the Observable from `forkJoin`.

Comment: @displayname do not return a Subscription. It has to be an Observable! Set the data in a pipe with tap or something. Like this: https://pastecode.xyz/view/ab506506

Comment: Ah, I guess I need to use `exhaustMap` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50575875/826983

Comment: If you could expand your answer a little bit s.t. it contains the relevant code I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If the child component are displayed by routing, then using resolvers might be a good option. Here is an example of doing so in the [doc](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

If the parent component is simply calling the child component by using the child component tag, then `*ngIf` will be a good option - something like this

```
<child-component *ngIf="condition"></child-component>
```

Last option, would be to use `ngOnInit` to initialize the data in the child component.

Comment: I updated my quesiton. `*ngIf` is already my weapon of choice but it breaks as I refresh the page. In this case, the data is not loaded and my `condition` is `true`. (the condition asks for *not null*)

Comment: Maybe you need to use this condition instead `"business && !business?.servicePlan"`

Comment: This was suggested in another comment. I tried it but this only works in 50% of the time.

Comment: I think you need to tune that condition to satisfy your need.